# Referenced DLL is copied to output directory but not included in ClickOnce deployment

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, quicktime

I'm having trouble deploying QuickTime references using ClickOnce in VS2010. The app runs just fine when run locally, but not when deployed. I tracked it down to a missing DLL during installation.

These are the included references in my project:

```
AxQTOControlLib
QTOControlLib
QTOLibrary
```

When I publish my app, it creates:

```
AxInterop.QTOControlLib.dll.deploy
Interop.QTOControlLib.dll.deploy
Interop.QTOLibrary.dll.deploy
```

The problem is when I actually install the app `Interop.QTOLibrary.dll.deploy` is nowhere to be found in the installation directory.

The other thing I noticed is in Publish -> Application Files, `Interop.QTOLibrary.dll` is not listed.

I've tried adjusting the Isolated value but that doesn't have an affect. I also tried manually including `Interop.QTOLibrary.dll` but then I hit hash mismatch issues.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of fiddling, I got it working.

The fix was to set `Copy Local = true` and `Isolated = true` for all 3 QuickTime references.

I also manually included a copy of `Interop.QTOLibrary.dll` but set `Build Action = None` and `Copy to Output = Never` per these instructions: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/fcb2008b-e442-4c49-aa7a-0acb1ef0e210. Not sure if that helped though.

Comment: What did you mean by `Isolated = true`? I see the `Copy Local` option in the reference's Properties window. However, I do not see `Isolated`.